# What is the best practice for validating field data in large upload from the web?

Tags: php, sql-server, regex, database

Well I will explain what I'm doing.

I need to validate files with restricted data, that comes with more than 100k rows each with 120 fields, each field has his own validation according to defined format, for example "COD234-ES" and so other distinct formats,

I need to insert this data into table from a database in SQL SERVER 2008, but before insert this data must be validated.

This files must be uploaded from clients through web interface made in a PHP framework.

My question in terms of performance and efficiency, is which is the best practice to do this?

First validate on client side then upload, first upload to server then use PHP to validating or upload an bulk insert into database and then validate with transact -sql ?

With many validations i thought to use REGEX expressions but in SQL is l

I appreciate who can guide me to make this in the best way. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to validate as early as possible.

If you can validate on the client, always do so as it will save the clients network bandwidth as well as server loading. You are likely to have more clients than servers.

If you can validate in the PHP, that's better than the database, because it's usually easier to spread the load across multiple web servers and keep a single database, rather than shard the database across several servers.

Comment: But also validate on your end. Never trust what the client sends you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is, you have to validate both on the client side and on the server.
On the client side, because it's far too user unfriendly to upload much data, then get an errror message.

But then, you need to revalidate on the server, as an evil person (or an automated upload interface) can circumvent your client side testing, and intentionally or by stupidity introduce garbage or malicious data.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with rjmunro and Quandary, validate your data on client side and on server side. It isn't very useful to rerevalidate with transact-sql (or only in test phase) but you can make constraints checks when you create your tables.